# Using Open Weather Map APi

Tags: android, json, weather-api

I have contacted Open Weather Map support team last week and their forum is dead. Hopefully get some help on here.

I am currently building a weather app for android.

when I send the lat and long for Birmingham UK
which are
lat 52.4447615﹕
 lon -1.9292798

it returns Vietnam as the country with a completely different lat lang?  I know open weather map is very popular so I must be constructing the url wrong or

something.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=lat=52.4447462&lon=-1.9292798&units=metric
```

would really appreciate any help. Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is the units argument. Just get rid of it and it works:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=52.4447615&lon=-1.9292798
```

Please note I have not read through the API documentation, just started from their overview page here:
http://openweathermap.org/current.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You are correct of course. I'll have to look at another way to sort the metrics (or convert them myself)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [[openweathermap.org]](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=52&lon=-1)[1](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=52&lon=-1)

You can also use `Geocoder` to get city name from co-ordinates.